# T-SQL 2005: Add Date and Time

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, dateadd

I have two fields which are both Datetime type:

```
Date = '2011-1-01 00:00:00.000'
Time = '1900-01-01 3:31:19.000'
```

The '1900-01-01' is the default value so I am interested only in the time part (3:31:19.000).

All what I want is to combine Date and time together. So, for this example i want a query which would give me the result:

```
Combined = '2011-1-01 3:31:19.000'
```

I am using T-SQL 2005.

Comment: Are the times always the same 1900?

Comment: Do you have a primary key?How would you merge the dates?

Comment: Yes, the value for the time would be always 1900-01-01

Comment: @Mihai: I do have a primary key. For simplicity of this example, I would just wanna know how to merge those 2 fields.Multumesc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a string-less  option, you can stack DATEADD/DATEPART operators together...

```
DECLARE @Date DATETIME = '2011-1-01 00:00:00.000'
, @Time DATETIME = '1900-01-01 3:31:19.000'

SELECT DATEADD(hh, DATEPART(hh, @Time), DATEADD(mi, DATEPART(mi, @Time), @Date)) --and so on
```

Results in `2011-01-01 03:31:00.000`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

- *Convert(date,...)* --strips time
- *Convert(varchar(),..,108)* --strips
  date

Query

```
select  Convert(date,'2011-1-01 00:00:00.000') 
             +' '+ convert(varchar(20),'1900-01-01 3:31:19.000',108)
```

Comment: I am using 2005 version so this will not work for me (getting this error: Type date is not a defined system type.)